# How to Override the default behaviour of keyboard keys in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using `Silverlight 4.0`,in which i am trying to develop a web application.In this application i am implementing `keyboard` shortcuts like `Ctrl+c,Ctrl+U etc..`In browsers while using `Ctrl+U`, debugging window is opening.Is there any way to Override these default behaviours?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding an `eventListner` to the document.

```
       document.addEventListener('keydown', keydownevent);

       function keydownevent (event){
            if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 85){
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("You have pressed ctrl+u")
            }
        }
```

Now the document will always listen for the `keydown event`. In order to remove this event you need to remove the eventListner from the document when the socpe of your page ends as

```
document.removeEventListener('keydown', keydownevent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` if you wish to prevent the default actions assigned.

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
   //verify the control press you want to prevent and call preventDefault()
   //ex : if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 84)
   e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: I need to access Ctrl+U keys together,which is not accessible through Javascript.

Comment: @VVN actually you can, `e.ctrlKey` will be `true` if Ctrl key is pressed. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ctrlkey.asp